# Bypass duplicate record when one table data is inserted from another in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to insert data from one database table to another database table. This work is performed very well but need bypass that duplicate data cannot be inserted. Here is my query below. How can I check duplicate record?

```
;WITH ABC AS (
    SELECT 
    5 AS DeviceID
    , nUserID AS CardNo
    , CONVERT(DATE, dbo.fn_ConvertToDateTime(nDateTime)) AS InOutDate
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(8) ,CONVERT(TIME,dbo.fn_ConvertToDateTime(nDateTime))) AS InOutTime
    FROM [BioStar].[dbo].[TB_EVENT_LOG]
)
SELECT * INTO #tempAtten FROM ABC

INSERT [HR].[dbo].[HR_DeviceInOut](DeviceID, CardNo, InOutDate, InOutTime, ShiftprofileID, ExecutedBy)
SELECT DeviceID, CardNo, InOutDate, InOutTime, NULL, NULL
FROM #tempAtten
WHERE #tempAtten.InOutDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND #tempAtten.CardNo <> 0 

DROP TABLE #tempAtten
```

**--HR_DeviceInOut**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HR_DeviceInOut](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(100000000000001,1) NOT NULL,
    [DeviceID] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [CardNo] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [InOutDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [InOutTime] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ShiftprofileID] [tinyint] NULL,
    [ExecutedBy] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_HR_AttenHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**--Function**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ConvertToDateTime] (@Datetime BIGINT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LocalTimeOffset BIGINT
           ,@AdjustedLocalDatetime BIGINT;
    SET @LocalTimeOffset = DATEDIFF(second,GETDATE(),GETUTCDATE())
    SET @AdjustedLocalDatetime = @Datetime - @LocalTimeOffset
    RETURN (SELECT DATEADD(second,@AdjustedLocalDatetime, CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS datetime)))
END;
```

Comment: You should post the table structure of the `HR_DeviceInOut` table. What is the `primary key` of that table?

Comment: @sgeddes, I have updated my table structure.

Comment: Oh, you aren't having an error with your query, you just don't want to insert duplicate rows.  If so, what defines a duplicate?  Duplicates being inserted or existing data being duplicated?  Perhaps `not exists`, or perhaps some subquery with `row_number`.

Comment: @sgeddes, HR_DeviceInOut table data cannot be duplicated by DeviceID, CardNo, InOutDate, InOutTime

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding correctly, here's one option using `not exists`:

```
INSERT [HR].[dbo].[HR_DeviceInOut] (DeviceID, CardNo, InOutDate, 
                                    InOutTime, ShiftprofileID, ExecutedBy)
SELECT DeviceID, CardNo, InOutDate, InOutTime, NULL, NULL
FROM #tempAtten t
WHERE t.InOutDate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) AND 
    t.CardNo <> 0 AND 
    NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM [HR].[dbo].[HR_DeviceInOut] d
         WHERE t.DeviceID = d.DeviceId AND 
               t.CardNo = d.CardNo AND
               t.InOutDate = d.InOutDate AND 
               t.InOutTime = d.InOutTime
      )
```

Consider adding a `unique_index` to the those fields that cannot be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Which column set make record unique as i see some column are hard coded

ie 5 AS DeviceID ...

Create unique key for rest of the column in temp table and destinationtabel.to avoid duplicate .